# Http/1.1 Service Unavailable in load balancing servers

Tags: php

Http/1.1 Service Unavailable means?

I have 9 servers. With load balancer am connecting servers.

Out of 5 sites, 3 sites working fine.

Two sites  throws the error : Http/1.1 Service Unavailable

What is the reason for that errors?

Comment: @Hanky Panky: yes i googled, but couldn't find the reason.

Comment: @KryDos : log file entry like this (IP ADDRESS(Ex:192.168.1.1) - - - [01/Feb/2013:00:22:06 -0600] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 403 - "-" "-") – Kaspar Mary

Answer (score 1):

So you have 9 servers that have 5 sites spread across all 9 servers (Mirrored) and the LB is giving `Http/1.1 Service Unavailable` when you view two of the sites?

It seems the back end servers are giving a 5XX error when the LB is trying talk to the back end servers. `Http/1.1 Service Unavailable` is a pretty general error you have given us. I would say it's something with your domains not configured with the back end server correctly.

What OS are you using? What else apache?.....

Comment: @Danieal : Apache 2.0. also how could i check the back end servers?

Comment: @KasparMary do you have access to the back end servers? You say your log is showing `403` that could be it. That means your back end servers (9 servers) could be denying traffic to the load balancer. Maybe you have some sort of module that limits request per IP but wouldn't explain why just on two domains.